# Ternary expression on properties of ion-badge?

Tags: angular, ionic2, ternary-operator

Is it possible to use ternary expressions on properties of `ion-badge`?

I have tried without success:

```
<ion-badge color="earthquake.properties.mag<4?primary:danger">

<ion-badge color="earthquake.properties.mag<4?'primary':'danger'">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following options

```
[color]="earthquake.properties.mag < 4 ? 'primary' : 'danger'"


color="{{ earthquake.properties.mag < 4 ? 'primary' : 'danger' }}"
```

Comment: The first one is does not work but the second (so far)